# Trying to learn module.exports but having some problem

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js from some week and now I would like to do that when someone enter in a vocal chat, the bot will send a message in the console. I tried using this code in the main file of the bot and perfectly worked but when I try to put it in another file and export it in the main file it doesn't work. Someone that can help me and maybe explain it?
`main.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("../config.json");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection(); 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

const a = require("./commands/test1")
if(client.guilds.cache.get("<guild if>")){
    return a
}
```

`test1.js`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token } = require("../config.json");

module.exports = {
    execute() {
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (newState.channelID === null) console.log('Inside channel',  oldState.channelID);
    else if (oldState.channelID === null) console.log('Outside channel', newState.channelID);
    else console.log('user moved channels', oldState.channelID, newState.channelID);
})}}
```

Comment: Can you update your post with a main file importing and using the test1.js?

Comment: Done. I updated main.js

Answer (score 0):

In this part in your `main.js` file:

```js
const a = require("./commands/test1")
if(client.guilds.cache.get("<guild if>")){
    return a
}
```

The `a` variable contains an object like `{ execute: function(){...} }`. You not calling the execute function.

Try this:

```js
const { execute } = require("./commands/test1")
if(client.guilds.cache.get("<guild if>")){
    return execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the keyword `function` before the word `execute()`?

Alternatively, you could do:

```js
//                       \/ you can put arguments here
module.exports.execute = () => {
  // function here
}
```

and then in your index file..

```js
const a = require("./commands/test1")
if(client.guilds.cache.get("<guild if>")){
    return a.execute(this is where you would put your arguments)
}
```

Happy coding!